# How to Delete files after certain time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, setinterval, multer

Here is the code which allows to upload files. Which I want to delete If lastClick (defined at download.js) is 1 day.

```
let storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: (req, file, cb) => cb(null, 'uploads/'),
      filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const uniqueName = `${Date.now()}-${Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9)}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`;
        cb(null, uniqueName)
      }
    });
    
let upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 16106119114
  },
}).single('file'); //100mb


router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  upload(req, res, async (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send({
        error: err.message
      });
    }

    const file = new File({
      guploadBy: req.user.googleId,
      fuploadBy: req.user.facebookId,
      tuploadBy: req.user.twitterId,
      uploaderName: req.user.name,
      fileName: req.file.filename,
      originalName: req.file.originalname,
      provider: req.user.provider,
      path: req.file.path,
      fileSize: Math.round((req.file.size * (1 / 1000000))),
      adultContent: req.body.select,
      uuid_s: shortid.generate(),
      uuid_d: uuidv4()
    });
    const response = await file.save();

});
```

Below I have written code to delete the files after (lastClick + 1 Day) and this should run every 1 min.

```
setInterval(findRemoveSync.bind(this,__dirname + '/uploads', {age: {seconds: 60}}), req.file.lastClick+86,400,000)
```

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with my code?

Comment: The nodejs `setInterval()` function takes the interval in milliseconds as the second argument, so your code will run every `lastClick + 86400000` milliseconds